# How can I close a Popover programatically with native base?

Tags: react-native, native-base

I am using [Native Base Popover](https://docs.nativebase.io/popover#page-title).

**scenario**
As a user,
I can press on the list,
So that I can select a fruit

[image]

My problem is I don't understand how to close the `<Popover />` from the outside of the component.

Here is my organization

```js
<Formik>
  <Popover>
    <FlatList>
      <Pressable onPress={() => handlePress(item.id)} /> //Banaba
      <Pressable onPress={() => handlePress(item.id)} /> //Potato
      <Pressable onPress={() => handlePress(item.id)} /> //Ananas
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NativeBase offers [a `useDisclose()` hook](https://docs.nativebase.io/use-disclose) for handling opening/closing of modals and other popup windows.

That hook provides an `isOpen` state (as @mainak's answer mentions) as well as `onOpen()` and `onClose()` functions to manipulate that state. You can pass these helpers as arguments as-needed into the props of the same name within the Popover component to handle open/close state.

Optionally, you can in addition pass `true` or `false` into `useDisclose()` to override the starting value of `isOpen` (defaults to `false`).

Here is an example below for reference.

```
import React from "react";
import { Popover, useDisclose } from "native-base";

function MyComponent() {
  const { isOpen, onClose, onOpen } = useDisclose()

  return (
    <>
      <Button onPress={onOpen}>Open the Popover</Button>
      <Popover isOpen={isOpen} onClose={onClose}>
        <Popover.Content>
          <Popover.Arrow />
          <Popover.CloseButton />
          <Popover.Header>My Popover Title</Popover.Header>
          <Popover.Body>You can place the content of your popover inside the body.</Popover.Body>
          <Popover.Footer>
            <Button onPress={onClose} variant="ghost">Cancel</Button>
          </Popover.Footer>
        </Popover.Content>
      </Popover>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Nice!

I just need to add an extra `onClose` to `<Pressable onPress={() => { onClose(); handlePress(item.id)}} />` and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

can you try isOpen prop in Popover tag and have it as a state value like

```
const [isOpen, setOpen] = React.useState(true);
...

<Formik>
  <Popover isOpen={isOpen}>
    <FlatList>
      ...
```